# Finding density of each community in a network using cdlib

Tags: graph, networkx

I am using cdlib library to discover communities in a network using leiden algorithm. The method to discover communities is straightforward. The following code does it:

```
from cdlib import algorithms
import networkx as nx
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
coms = algorithms.leiden(G)
```

I am, however, stuck as to how to find density of each community. I will be grateful for any help. (Even though this question does not directly pertain to networkx library, I am tagging networkx as cdlib is not present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coms.scaled_density(summary=False)` to calculate densities of the individual communities.
[Read doc](https://cdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/classes/fuzzy_node_clustering.html#cdlib.FuzzyNodeClustering.scaled_density) for rest of the arguments.